# Pull NA from Match Function

Tags: r

So I want to pull the NA value from a match function to assign it a value later in the code. Here is an example of what I am working with.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
test <- match(x,y)
test
```

Which gives an output of:

```
[1] NA  1  2  3  4
```

Then I attempted to find where test is NA using the which function.

```
test2 <- which(test == NA)
```

This gives an output of:

```
integer(0)
```

The desired output would be `1` and then I could do something like

```
x[test2] <- 0
```

Comment: Try `is.na(test)` instead of `==NA`  i.e. `x[is.na(test)] <- 0`

Comment: Worked perfectly, should have remembered the is.na() function